# Use search.php for custom search results? Also wp query pagination not working

Tags: wordpress

I am making a filter plugin and I want to use the search.php for the results, but if I set text input name to 's' in my plugin, then it uses the regular search functionality, not the WP_Query method I set up in my plugin.

And if I change the name and make the plugin use that name, I get the results but in the same place where the plugin itself appear.

So, can I somehow make the search.php page use the results from my plugin?

the form and my query:

```
<?php

    $blog_url = get_bloginfo('url');

    $form = <<<EOH
    <div id="sbc">
    <form method="get" action="{$blog_url}" id="ss-search">
        <input type="text" value="{$search_text}" name="ss" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value = '{$search_text}';}" onfocus=if (this.value == '{$search_text}') { this.value = '';}" />
        {$list}
        <input type="submit" id="sbc-submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
    </div>
EOH;

if (isset($_GET['ss'])) {
        $args = array(
            // 'category__not_in' => 1,
            's' => $_GET['ss']
        );

        $q = new WP_Query($args);

        if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
                echo '<ul>';
            while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
                $q->the_post();
                echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
            }
                echo '</ul>';
                echo get_pagination_links();
        } else {
            echo 'no posts found';

        }
        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    echo $form;

?>
```

search.php

```
<p class="search_results">Your search for <span class="searchterm"><?php the_search_query(); ?></span> has returned <?php echo $totalresults; ?> results.</p>

<?php

global $paged;
if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

$loop_counter = 1;

$results_per_page = get_query_var('posts_per_page');

echo '<ul class="search-list">';

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

  if( $paged == 1 ) {
    $real_count = $loop_counter;
  } else {
    $real_count = $loop_counter + ( $paged * $results_per_page - $results_per_page);
  }

  echo '<li><span class="listnum">' . $real_count . '.</span>';

  // The Post
  ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 46);?>...</a> 

  <?php

  echo '</li>';

  // genesis_after_post();

  $loop_counter++;

  endwhile;
  // genesis_after_endwhile();

else :
  // genesis_loop_else();
    echo '<p>No results found. Search for "page" for best results.';
endif;

echo '</ul>';

?>
```

Also, pagination doesn't work witht the custom WP_Query ($q). I DO get pagination links, but they don't work. For example if I click on the second page, nothing happens. If I change `$q` to `$wp_query` it works, but then I can't pass it the arguments I want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I spent a lot of time trying to resolve the same issue I believe and only to find lots of suggestions about how to reset a query using `wp_reset_query` (which for a seasoned dev is fairly predictable).

What I did find out is that essentially the issue had nothing to do with the query within my search.php, but had everything to do with the querystring from simply being on the search results page, so within my shortcode or plugin I simply set the global wp_query is_search method to false and BAM! finally getting my expected results.

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->is_search = false;
```

Try that out let me know how it works for you. As long as you make that change before you declare your own `WP_Query($args)` you should be fine.

Comment: I actually solved this a while back, I ended up using the powerful WP Query itself with its arguments and it worked with search.php , the thing was to use the `set` method. If you need help with this let me know. Personally I never saw that method until some good soul here introduced me to it.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, did not see an answer provided so figured I'd post mine. Good luck